# C# ExecuteReader not returning SQL query data in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm having trouble extracting the SQL data I need from the below query.  I've looked on MSDN and followed their examples, but for some reason the executereader is not reading the data and returning it to the textbox, after clicking the button.  I have added a response to ensure the connection is open, and it is each time pressed.  This is an extract of the code, the only thing I have omitted from here is the sqlconnection detail:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            //set up the SQL command       
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Use Waste_Test; select * from Bidston_HWRC where MCN_No = @MCN", conn);

            //open the server connection
            conn.Open();

            //define parameter for SQL query
            command.Parameters.Add("@MCN", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@MCN"].Value = TextBox17.Text;

            Response.Write("<script>alert('You are connected')</script>");


            //Execute the query on the server
            SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

            Response.Write("<script>alert('It's worked')</script>");

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                TextBox6.Text = rdr["Waste_Description"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're saying the parameter is of type int and then giving it a string, perhaps this has something to do with it?

Comment: try using command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MCN", TextBox17.Text); considering casting type as int as mentioned by  Lasse V. Karlsen. if required type for parameter is integer.

Comment: Why do you *loop* `while (rdr.Read())` for *one* value only? `if (rdr.Read()) TextBox6.Text = rdr["Waste_Description"].ToString();`

Comment: `command.Parameters["@MCN"].Value = int.Parse(TextBox17.Text);`

Comment: did you test your query in SQL server? have you got any result?

Comment: Hi @Saif, yes, I tested the query in SQL server and it gave the correct result.

Comment: you have 2 parameters but in slqCommand you just have only one?

Comment: No @Saif, OP uses 1 parameter. It's just splited in two lines,one for definition and the other to assign value

Comment: Hi All, have tried all of the above, thank you for your suggestions, but have still not had any luck so far.  Will try using ExecuteScalar, as it is only the one result needed from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you need to use `HasRows`in order to ensure that query return some result, if no record return then you can show a message in label. Since you are getting the `MCN` value from textbox, then you need to parse it into int. Try the following code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {     
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Bidston_HWRC where MCN_No = @MCN", conn);
            conn.Open();
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCN", Int32.Parse(TextBox17.Text));
            //Execute the query on the server
            SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();



        if(rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
              TextBox6.Text = rdr["Waste_Description"].ToString();
            }

        }
        else
        {
          // show 'no records found'
        }
       rdr.Close();
       conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? I guess it's going to throw a `IndexOutOfRangeException` in this line -> `command.Parameters["@MCN"].Value = Int32.Parse(TextBox17.Text);`

Comment: just changed to `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCN", Int32.Parse(TextBox17.Text);` and I tried to parse text into int due to the value needs to be in int...

Comment: Hi @Pikoh, you are correct, it did throw that error out.  How would you correct that? Thanks

Comment: @kehoewex86 use saif updated answer (using `AddWithValue`) or just as you had it, using add and then `.Value = int.Parse(TextBox17.Text);`

Comment: @kehoewex86 my pleasure to hear that